# iOS GCD Sync and Async

Tags: swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to figure out how sync and async methods work in GCD, but I made some test and don't really understand the result. This is a code from Playground

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queueA = DispatchQueue(label: "my-awesome-queue")
let queueB = DispatchQueue(label: "one-more-awesome-queue", attributes: .concurrent)

for _ in 0...5 {
    queueA.sync {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.2)
        print("")
    }
}

for _ in 0...5 {
    queueB.async {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.2)
        print("")
    }
}
```

And result is

I don't really understand, why queueA blocks async tasks from other queue (queueB)? I thought different queues could be executed from different threads, and there are no problems to run sync queue and different async queue simultaneously. Or custom sync queues block any other queues (even main queue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically using `sync` from the main thread is always wrong, because now you are blocking the main thread. And that is exactly what you are doing! Only a background thread should `sync` onto another thread.

> and there are no problems to run sync queue and different async queue simultaneously

Yes, there are. Nothing can happen "simultaneously". Everything has to "take turns".

> Or custom sync queues block any other queues (even main queue)?

Yes. While Queue A is being called with `sync` and is sleeping, the calling thread (which in your code is the main thread) is blocked. You are not allowing things to "take turns". We cannot proceed to the Queue B calls because we are stuck in the Queue A calls.

You will also notice that the Queue B results arrive much faster than the Queue A results did. That is because Queue B is being called with `async` and is concurrent, so the whole second loop, when it runs, runs immediately, doing all the loops, and so all the results arrive together. This is even more obvious if you print `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` together with your output.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Processors with N-cores can execute N-tasks simultaneously for sure ;) But I got what you meant, thanks!

Comment: Basically using `sync` from the main thread is always wrong, because now you are blocking the main thread. Only a background thread should `sync` onto another thread. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: To say it is “always wrong” to `sync` from main queue is obviously too strong of a claim. E.g., we use `sync` from main when using GCD to synchronizing reads of a variable as part of a broader thread-safe strategy, for example. But for anything that could take more than a few milliseconds, then, yes, don’t use `sync` from the main thread, as that’s a blocking call. But where (a) `sync` is required and (b) you know it can’t block except fleetingly, then it may well be the right tool for the job.